# Creating a huge BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

He guys,
I want to create a huge BufferedImage in Java with the dimension 20000 x 20000 or bigger, but Java throws the following Exception:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

How can I avoid this Exception? Is it even possible that Java creates such big images?

Comment: How big is your heap?

Comment: Which java version are you using? What is the size of image? how much RAM is available?

Comment: @ sAm jre: 1.8.0_111 size: 20000 x 20000 RAM: 4GB

Comment: Why do you need such big image for? Just wondering.

Comment: @user3437460 mapping primes

Comment: What kind of image do you need? With full RGB (24 bits/pixel), or would simple black&white (1 bit/pixel) be enough?

Comment: @Thomas Fritsch simple black&white would be okay also. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

While it's certainly easier to just increase your heap size, I've created a special `DataBuffer` implementation, that allows you to keep `BufferedImage`s memory outside the heap. It's using a NIO memory mapped file buffer, and works similar to virtual memory. It's way slower than using a normal `BufferedImage`, but might help you load and process images that would otherwise be too large.

See [MappedImageFactory.java](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedImageFactory.java) and [MappedFileBuffer.java](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedFileBuffer.java) for the implementation (BSD licensed).

Usage would be as simple as:

```
int w = 20000;
int h = 20000;
BufferedImage image = MappedImageFactory
                   .createCompatibleMappedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

I've successfully used it to load and display a 2 GB image with as little as 32 MB heap.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure, to use 64 bit java and 64 bit system:

*On most modern 32-bit Windows systems the maximum heap size will range from 1.4G to 1.6G. On 32-bit Solaris kernels the address space is limited to 2G. On 64-bit operating systems running the 32-bit VM, the max heap size can be higher, approaching 4G on many Solaris systems.*

then add some heap:

try -Xmx2048m or -Xmx2g

to your "java" invocation (JVM arguments)

Because if you are using RGB or ARGB type of image, then every pixel is type `int`

20 000 x 20 000= 400 000 000 * 4 (int has 4 bytes) = ~400MB * 4 = ~1600 MB

assuming you wish to have even bigger images and your app needs some space as well as JVM you might wish to have more or less heap, you need to decide.

If you have 4GB of RAM, as you stated in some comment below your question, this can limit the size of image you can create, you need to subtract from the 4GB the amount of ram for system, other apps, JVM, then you can't create an image bigger than the memory you have been left with.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do I have to add the heap with the cmd?

Comment: You need to passs the -Xmx... as a argument to the JVM during its start. If you are using cmd line, then to the java invocation, if eclipse, then to the "JVM arguments" of the "run configuration" for your project.

Comment: I'm working with Eclipse and there are two fields: Program Arguments and VM arguments. I tried inserting the command but it's returning the same Exception

Answer (score 0):

You can create a black&white image (1 bit/pixel) like this:

```
    IndexColorModel colorModel = new IndexColorModel(
            1,                           // bits per pixel
            2,                           // number of colors
            new byte[]{0, (byte) 0xff},  // red values
            new byte[]{0, (byte) 0xff},  // green values
            new byte[]{0, (byte) 0xff}); // blue values
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(20000, 20000,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY, colorModel);
```

Would need 20000 * 20000 bits = 50 MB.

Comment: Clever.  Actually, `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` has a b/w `IndexColorModel` by default, so you could simplify the above to just `new BufferedImage(20000, 20000, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);`